# Trying to summarize specific field in Report Builder

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I am new to Microsoft Report Builder and I need help building a report that shows the number of clients who have used a service within a time period. My focus right now is getting a correct sum of the Client ID's, which should show the total number of individuals who have used the service. Within the Report Builder dataset properties, I have the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN CAST(LastTripDate AS char(8)) = '0' THEN CAST('18000101' AS date )
    ELSE CAST(CAST(LastTripDate AS char(8))      AS date )
    END
,CL.ClientID
,CL.LastName
,CL.FirstName
From dbo.vITS_Clients CL
  INNER JOIN ABBooking BK
    ON CL.ClientId = BK.ClientId
Where LastTripDate > 20230501
AND LastTripDate < 20230531
```

When I attempt to summarize the ClientID field, it produces a count of 155, when the number provided through the application report says 547. My theory is that a count distinct function within the Field Properties should help provide the total, but I am struggling to complete it. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance,
David

Comment: 18000101 - which client was traveling Jan 1st, the year 1800?

Comment: what expression have you tried? something like `=CountDistinct(Fields!ClientID.Value, "myDataSetName")` will give you the number if distinct CLientIOD's in the entire dataset/ Also, what datatype is LastTripDate and why do you need the `CASE` statement as it wont; have any affect in the query because you are only returning dates within a valid range.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I tried using a count distinct expression and it gave me a result, but it did not match what I was given from the application report. The case statement was used to convert the date from a string to a date format as we plan to filter the data on specific date periods

Comment: @jarlH we did not have clients travelling that long ago, we wanted an arbitrary date that would stand out so we could exclude them.

Comment: You'll probably need to edit your question, provide some sample data as text (or better still create a fiddle) and then the expected output from this sample data. This should be pretty simple so I guess there is something that is not clear from your question as it stands.